# $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{3}}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 3$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

We know that $[\mathbb{Q}(\omega \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{3}}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 3$ and $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) : \mathbb{Q}] = 2$, where $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity.

My algebra instructor then made the claim that this implies that $\omega \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{3}} \notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Why does this claim follow ?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if it is in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that was the case, then surely we'd have $\Bbb Q(\omega\cdot 2^{\frac{1}{3}}) \subset \Bbb Q(\sqrt 2)$. But by considering the degrees you've already computed, that's impossible.

Comment: And, that is impossible due to the fact that $3 > 2$, correct ?

Comment: @michiganbiker898 due to the fact that $3$ doesn't divide $2$, to be precise. That's because of the tower law.

Comment: Oh man. I should have seen that earlier. Thanks a lot for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

If $K\subset E\subset F$ are field extensions, we have
$$[F:K]=[F:E]\cdot[E:K].$$